# Creating frequency interval in Crystal Report

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, crystal-reports

I am trying to create a dataset of frequency interval in crystal report something like below. First column is rowid, second is start interval , third column is end interval and fourth column is interval name.

```
1   0   29  0 - 29
2   30  59  30 - 59
3   60  89  60 - 89
4   90  119 90 - 119
5   120 149 120 - 149
6   150 179 150 - 179
7   180 209 180 - 209
8   210 239 210 - 239
9   240 269 240 - 269
10  270 299 270 - 299
11  300 329 300 - 329
12  330 359 330 - 359
13  360 389 360 - 389
14  390 419 390 - 419
15  420 449 420 - 449
16  450 479 450 - 479
17  480 509 480 - 509
18  510 539 510 - 539
19  540 569 540 - 569
20  570 599 570 - 599
21  600 629 600 - 629
22  630 659 630 - 659
23  660 689 660 - 689
24  690 719 690 - 719
25  720 749 720 - 749
26  750 779 750 - 779
27  780 809 780 - 809
28  810 839 810 - 839
29  840 869 840 - 869
30  870 899 870 - 899
```

Can I write a CTE to generate this interval so that I can use it directly in crystal report without writing function on database side? Below is the code which I wrote:

```
declare intervalStart integer := 0;
        intervalEnd integer := 900;
        intervalMins varchar(10) := 30;
        totalIntervals number := 0;

begin
    begin
        execute immediate 'create global temporary table intervalTable  (row_Id int not null, intStart integer, intEnd integer, intervalName varchar2(25))ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS';
        exception when others then dbms_output.put_line(sqlerrm);
    end;
    totalIntervals := intervalEnd/intervalMins;
    --dbms_output.put_line(totalIntervals);

    for i in 1 ..totalIntervals loop
        intervalStart := 0;
        intervalEnd := 0;
        intervalStart := intervalStart + (i-1)*intervalMins;
        intervalEnd := intervalEnd + (i*intervalMins)-1;
        --dbms_output.put_line(intervalStart || ' - ' || intervalEnd);
        insert into intervalTable 
        (
            row_id,
            intStart,
            intEnd,
            intervalName
        )
        values(i, intervalStart, intervalEnd, (intervalStart || ' - ' || intervalEnd));
    end loop;


end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
with freq_data as (
    select level as id, (level-1)*30 as start_interval, ((level-1)*30) + 29 as end_interval, (level-1)*30 || ' - ' || to_char(((level-1)*30) + 29) as label
    from dual
    connect by level <= 30
    order by level
)
select * from freq_data;
```

Output

```
ID  START_INTERVAL  END_INTERVAL    LABEL
1   0   29  0 - 29
2   30  59  30 - 59
3   60  89  60 - 89
4   90  119 90 - 119
5   120 149 120 - 149
6   150 179 150 - 179
7   180 209 180 - 209
8   210 239 210 - 239
9   240 269 240 - 269
10  270 299 270 - 299
11  300 329 300 - 329
12  330 359 330 - 359
13  360 389 360 - 389
14  390 419 390 - 419
15  420 449 420 - 449
16  450 479 450 - 479
17  480 509 480 - 509
18  510 539 510 - 539
19  540 569 540 - 569
20  570 599 570 - 599
21  600 629 600 - 629
22  630 659 630 - 659
23  660 689 660 - 689
24  690 719 690 - 719
25  720 749 720 - 749
26  750 779 750 - 779
27  780 809 780 - 809
28  810 839 810 - 839
29  840 869 840 - 869
30  870 899 870 - 899
```

An example using the above in a join query:

```
create table my_test 
(
    num number
    -- other important data ...
);

-- insert some random numbers
insert into my_test
select trunc(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(0,900))
from dual
connect by level <= 10;
commit;
```

Now joining to get the label for each num field:

```
with freq_data as (
    select level as id, (level-1)*30 as start_interval, ((level-1)*30) + 29 as end_interval, (level-1)*30 || ' - ' || to_char(((level-1)*30) + 29) as label
    from dual
    connect by level <= 30
    order by level
)
select t.num, d.label
from my_test t
left join freq_data d ON (t.num between d.start_interval and d.end_interval);
```

Output:

```
NUM LABEL
64  60 - 89
73  60 - 89
128 120 - 149
154 150 - 179
267 240 - 269
328 300 - 329
550 540 - 569
586 570 - 599
745 720 - 749
795 780 - 809
```

Comment: Thanks @tbone for awesome response .. this is what I was looking for. I never heard of level. Thank you introducing this to me. But I did not understood the second part of code which you wrote.

Comment: @Ankur thanks, I was just giving a possible use case for joining to a CTE to get a label (range low/high values).  I've done something similar many times to generalize a data field.  For example, if I have a number that represents total yearly sales for a company, I might want to show a general sales range on a report "500,000 - 1,000,000" instead of 642,312 or whatever.  Anyway, maybe too much info lol